# One Constructor for a Class and its Nested Classes

Tags: c#, class, constructor, namespaces, nested

For the sake of this example, suppose we're making a dumbed-down game of *Clue™*.  We have a class for each Room in the mansion, and subclasses for the Suspect and Weapon in each Room. Something like:

```
class Room
{
  public string Name;
  public int Width;
  public int Height;
  // and so on...

  public class Suspect
  {
    public string Name;
    public bool isPurple;
  }

  public class Weapon
  {
    public string Name;
    public bool IsMetal;
  }
}
```

Before adding the Suspect and Weapon classes, the Room constructor looked something like:

```
public Room(string Name, int Width, int Height)
{
  this.Name = Name;
  this.Width = Width;
  this.Height = Height;
}
```

Initializing a room used to be as simple as: `Room[i] = new Room("Conservatory", 7, 3);` - but after the nested classes were introduced, can their initialization be handled through a shared constructor with the main class? Something like:

```
Room[i] = new Room("Library", 8, 5, "Professor Plum", true, "Candlestick", true);
```

I can't seem to find any examples of a similar setup. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: are you looking for something like this ParentClass.ChildClass childClass = new ParentClass.ChildClass();

Comment: A nested class has no particular relationship with its parent class.  Except that you can declare it private and thus completely hide it.  And that it can access private members of the outer class.  That's all, there is no scenario where a "shared constructor" would make sense.  Nor does it make sense to make the character class a private implementation detail of a room.

Comment: You don't find any examples because none could write an example for that, how can the compiler know that "Professor Plum" should be used as value for the Suspect.Name property? (I suppose that this is your intention)

Comment: How would you access the Weapon and Suspect instances from Room[0], Room[1], Room[2] etc...

Comment: A nested class does not mean that the nested class members are members of the containing class...  In fact I see really no reason to nest these classes, per se.

Comment: Why can't you just overload the constructor?

Comment: Since Suspect and Weapon are never changed after being first assigned to the Room, my intent was mostly to keep things clean - to organize the data such that, by giving a method access to Room, it would automatically get access to "Professor Plum's College Transcript" or some other detail that isn't necessarily about the Room itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having your constructor have so many parameters, why not do something like this?

```
public class Room
{
    public Room(Suspect suspect, Weapon weapon)
    {
        SuspectInRoom = suspect;
        WeaponInRoom = weapon;
    }

    public Suspect SuspectInRoom { get; set; }
    public Weapon WeaponInRoom { get; set; }
}

// Example usage:

Suspect coronelCustard = new Suspect("Coronel Custard");
Weapon musket = new Weapon("Musket");

Room someRoom = new Room(coronelCustard, musket);

// Then your room can be used to access all sorts of data.

Console.WriteLine(someRoom.SuspectInRoom.Nickname); // "The Big Kahuna"
Console.WriteLine(someRoom.WeaponInRoom.AttackDamage); // "20"
```

---

> When nested classes are introduced to a main class, can their
>   initialization be handled through a shared constructor with the main
>   class? Eventually I'd hope to initialize all three classes in the same
>   line...

If your nested class has a public constructor you can do that.

Example:

```
Room someRoom = new Room(new Suspect("Colonel Custard"), new Weapon("Musket"));
```

But, it's kind of a code smell to do things this way. It's better to use already created and instantiated members in constructor calls. It's a personal choice either way.

Comment: +1. but remember that in your code, a Room can have no name, which wasn't the case with the OP's constructor.

Comment: @ken2k: Oh yeah, he'd need to tweak this to his needs. I want to just illustrate how to better organize his classes.

Comment: I've never played a version of Clue in which a weapon's "attack damage" was important. After all, the only one "attacked" is dead at the beginning of the game. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need constructores... just use the initializers:

```
   var room = new Room { Name = "Library",
                         Width = 7,
                         Height = 3,
                         Suspect = new Suspect { Name = "Professor Plum",
                                                 PlaysCroquet = false },
                         Weapon = new Weapon { Name = "Candlestick",
                                               IsShiny = true }
                        };
```

Comment: Suspect and Weapon aren't fields in his example, they're nested classes.

Comment: The metaphor fell apart a little for me - the reason I was using the constructor was for future randomization of the fields.  Professor Plum doesn't necessarily go to the Library.

Comment: You are correct, and obviously my answer wouldn't compile, but we would assume that he would add properties to his primary class that references those classes.  Otherwise they would never be exposed.  Just because the classes are nested within this class doesn't mean they can't be externally referenced, just questionable design.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is to give the Suspect and Weapon classes public constructors, so they can be instantiated outside of the Room class (I assume this is acceptable, since the classes are declared public).

The Room constructor can then take references to a Suspect and a Weapon. This gives you the flexibility to create Suspect and Weapon objects at some prior point, and pass them into a Room on construction - it also prevents the Room class constructor from having to know about the Suspect and Weapon classes' properties (and requiring modification when you add to them).

For brevity, you can still construct all the objects in a single line, like so:

```
Room[i] = new Room("Library", 8, 5, new Suspect("Professor Plum", false), new Weapon("Candlestick", true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes by themselves don't need to be initialized, members are.

There are no formal restrictions on what arguments you pass to constructor and what members of the class you initialize in the constructor. If type of fields or properties happen to be nested class - it is no different than `int` or `string` from constructor's point of view<sup>*</sup>.

*: The only potential difference is members of type of non-public nested classes have to be initialized in some other method or constructor, unlike public read/write properties of which could be also set directly on instance of the class.